# Search and zip .jpg files within a range

Tags: grep, zip, amazon-ami

I have a folder with about 450k images in sequentially numbered. However, from about 0-200k there are quite a few gaps. I want to only zip any of the images from 0-200k into a folder.

I've been looking and grep -E keeps coming up but it looks like I'd have to specify all the ranges every 100 which isn't great.

Is there a quicker way to do it (on amazon linux)

The images are named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and so on to 199999.jpg

Comment: at least show us some example file names? are they `0001-0002.jpg`? or `foo1.jpg - foo1000.jpg`? we don't sit in front of your monitor.

Comment: they're 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about amazon linux but it worked on Ubuntu 17.10:

```
tar -czvf up_to_200K.tar.gz `for FILE in $(ls|grep -oP '^\d+(?=.jpg)'); do if [ $FILE -le 200000 ]; then echo $FILE.jpg;fi;done | xargs`
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try later. In the end I just uploaded them all to s3 and then used sync from that to the new directory to only pull the updated ones